# Can't make multiple if conditions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have absolutely no idea why this is not working.  Makes no sense to me.

This returns a "syntax error: parse error":

```
if ($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening = true) return false;
```

For good measure, I also tried the following, which yielded the same result:

```
if (1 = 1 && 2 = 2) { return false; }
```

Comment: is there any more code? because here it doesn't do anything wrong, except for assignment of opening.

Comment: @Igois: Why do you need more code? You can see quite clearly that the problem here is the use of a single equals is being used to determine equality in a statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three different operators at play:

- `=`: assignment
- `==`: equality
- `===`: strict equality

`=` **actually modifies** a variable, so you shouldn't use it inside `if` statements. That is, you should use `... || opening == true)` instead of `... || opening = true)`.

Comment: Note that using `=` in an `if` condition is (generally considered) bad practice but is still perfectly valid JS. The reason the code in the question gives an error is because operator precedence results in the expression being evaluated as `($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening) = true` and of course the first part `($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening)` is not a variable so it can't be assigned a value.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript `=` is used to assign values, while `==` and `===` are used to compare them.

When you put `opening = true` in your if statement, you aren't checking if `opening` is `true`, you are setting `opening` to `true`. Try using `==` instead.

For example,

```
var x = 5;
if (x == 10) {
    alert("x is 10");
} else {
    alert("x isn't 10");
}
```

will display "x isn't 10", while

```
var x = 5;
if (x = 10) {
    alert("x is 10");
} else {
    alert("x isn't 10");
}
```

will display "x is 10".

Comment: The second one is giving an error because you cannot assign `1` a value as it is not a valid variable name. Same for `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your condition

```
if ($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening = true) return false;
```

should be

```
if ($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening == true) return false;
```

the problem is with the equals sign

`=` is different to `==`

the first one is the assignment operator. the second one is for comparison

Answer (score 1):

the first example should read:

```
if ($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening == true) return false;
```

and the second:

```
if (1 == 1 && 2 == 2) { return false; }
```

Note the double equals (`==`) sign for logic equals is not the same as the single equals (`=`) sign, that handles variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you test like this:

```
opening=true;
```

What you are really doing is setting `opening` to the value of `true`.  Use `==` instead.

Finally, order of operations, even if correct, can get confusing.  Put parenthesis around each part of the comparison.

```
if (($(this).attr("id") === 'search') || (opening == true)) return false;
```

Answer (score -4):

My guess is that === does not exist.
== is for testing equality

so `if ($(this).attr("id") === 'search' || opening == true) return false;`
should be `if ($(this).attr("id") == 'search' || opening == true) return false;`

Comment: `===` compares value **and** type.  It definitely is a valid operator.