# Trying to check winners for JavaScript Tic Tac Toe Game but keeps getting Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, tic-tac-toe

I am new to JavaScript and was assigned to make a Tic Tac Toe game using only the canvas tag.
I have the canvas done, got the Xs and Os working, and now I am trying to write a code to check the winners.
After finishing, however, I received the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" for the first line under the function 'checkForWinners.'

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why and help me find a solution to fix it.

Thank you for your time.

P.S I do not know jquery.

```
<head>
    <title>Christin's Project 7</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="p6.css">  </link>
<script>
        var turn = 0;
        var winningCombinations;
        var content = new Array();
        var w1x;
        var w1o;
        var w2x;
        var w2o;
        var w3x;
        var w3o;
        var w4x;
        var w4o;
        var w5x;
        var w5o;
        var w6x;
        var w6o;
        var w7x;
        var w7o;
        var w8x;
        var w8o;
        var w9x;
        var w9o;
        var numfilled = 0;


        //window.onload = function() {
            //winningCombinations = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];  


        function canvasClicked() {   //calling canvas number
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            if(turn%2==0){
            ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx.closePath();//finished drawing
              var w1x = true;
             } else{
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
                var w1o = true;
                }
            turn++;
            numfilled++;
            content.push(1);
            if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }

            function canvasClicked2() { 
            var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
            var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
            if(turn%2==0){
             ctx2.beginPath();
             ctx2.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx2.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx2.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx2.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx2.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx2.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w2x = true;
             } else{
                ctx2.beginPath();
                ctx2.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx2.stroke();
                ctx2.closePath();
                var w2o = true;
                }
             turn++;
             numfilled++;
             content.push(2);
             if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }
            function canvasClicked3() { 
            var c3 = document.getElementById("myCanvas3");
            var ctx3 = c3.getContext("2d");
            if(turn%2==0){
             ctx3.beginPath();
             ctx3.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx3.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx3.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx3.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx3.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx3.closePath();//finished drawing
              var w3x = true;
            } else{
                ctx3.beginPath();
                ctx3.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx3.stroke();
                ctx3.closePath();
                var w3o = true;

                }
            turn++;
            numfilled++;
            content.push(3);
            if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }   
            function canvasClicked4() { 
            var c4 = document.getElementById("myCanvas4");
            var ctx4 = c4.getContext("2d");
            if(turn%2==0){
             ctx4.beginPath();
             ctx4.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx4.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx4.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx4.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx4.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx4.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w4x = true;
            } else{
                ctx4.beginPath();
                ctx4.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx4.stroke();
                ctx4.closePath();
                var w4o = true;

                }
            turn++;
            numfilled++;
            content.push(4);
            if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }
            function canvasClicked5() { 
            var c5 = document.getElementById("myCanvas5");
            var ctx5 = c5.getContext("2d");
            if(turn%2==0){
             ctx5.beginPath();
             ctx5.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx5.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx5.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx5.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx5.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx5.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w5x = true;
            } else{
                ctx5.beginPath();
                ctx5.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx5.stroke();
                ctx5.closePath();
                var w5o = true;

                }
            turn++;
            numfilled++;
            content.push(5);
            if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }
            function canvasClicked6() { 
            var c6 = document.getElementById("myCanvas6");
            var ctx6 = c6.getContext("2d");
            if(turn%2==0){
             ctx6.beginPath();
             ctx6.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx6.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx6.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx6.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx6.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx6.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w6x = true;
             } else{
                ctx6.beginPath();
                ctx6.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx6.stroke();
                ctx6.closePath();
                var w6o = true;
                }
             turn++;
             numfilled++;
             content.push(6);
             if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }
             function canvasClicked7() { 
             var c7 = document.getElementById("myCanvas7");
             var ctx7 = c7.getContext("2d");
             if(turn%2==0){
             ctx7.beginPath();
             ctx7.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx7.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx7.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx7.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx7.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx7.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w7x = true;
             } else{
                ctx7.beginPath();
                ctx7.arc(45,45,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx7.stroke();
                ctx7.closePath();
                var w7o = true;


            }
             turn++;
             numfilled++;
             content.push(7);
             if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }
             function canvasClicked8() { 
             var c8 = document.getElementById("myCanvas8");
             var ctx8 = c8.getContext("2d"); 
             if(turn%2==0){
             ctx8.beginPath();
             ctx8.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx8.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx8.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx8.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx8.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx8.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w8x = true;
             } else{
                ctx8.beginPath();
                ctx8.arc(45,45,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx8.stroke();
                ctx8.closePath();
                var w8o = true;
            }
             turn++;
             numfilled++;
             content.push(8);
             if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }
             function canvasClicked9() { 
             var c9 = document.getElementById("myCanvas9");
             var ctx9 = c9.getContext("2d");
             if(turn%2==0){
             ctx9.beginPath();
             ctx9.moveTo(150,0);//one line
             ctx9.lineTo(0,150);
             ctx9.moveTo(0,0); //the other line
             ctx9.lineTo(150,150);
             ctx9.stroke();//what actually draws the lines
             ctx9.closePath();//finished drawing
             var w9x = true;
             } else{
                ctx9.beginPath();
                ctx9.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                ctx9.stroke();
                ctx9.closePath();
                var w9o = true;
                }

            turn++;
            numfilled++;
            content.push(9);
            if(numfilled == 9){
                alert("THE GAME IS OVER!");
            }
        }

        function checkForWinners(){

        if( w1x = true w2x = true && w3x == true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        } 
        /*
        if(w4x = true && w5x = true && w6x = true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }

        if(w7x = true && w8x = true && w9x = true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }

        if(w1x = true && w4x = true && w7x == true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }

        if(w2x = true && w5x = true && w8x == true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }

        if(w3x = true && w6x = true && w9x == true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }

        if(w3x = true && w5x = true && w8x == true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }
        if(w1x = true && w5x = true && w9x == true) {
            alert( "X WON!");
        }



        if(w1o = true && w2o = true && w3o == true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }   

        if(w4o = true && w5o = true && w6o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }

        if(w7o = true && w8o = true && w9o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }

        if(w1o = true && w4o = true && w7o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }

        if(w2o = true && w5o = true && w8o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }

        if(w3o = true && w6o = true && w9o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }

        if(w3o = true && w5o = true && w8o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }

        if(w1o = true && w5o = true && w9o = true) {
            alert( "O WON!");
        }
    */  
    }


    </script>   

</head>







<body>
        <h3>Welcome </h3><h2>to</h2><h1> Tic - Tac - Toe!</h1>

        <h4> Instructions: To play Tic-tac-toe, you and another player take turns marking the spaces on the grid.<br> After assigning which player is the X or the O, The player who succeeds in placing three respective Xs or Os in a horizontal, vertical, or diagonal row wins the game.<br> If neither player succeeds, play again.</h4>

        <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked()"> </canvas> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked2()"> </canvas> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas3" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked3()"> </canvas> <br>
        <canvas id="myCanvas4" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked4()"> </canvas> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas5" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked5()"> </canvas> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas6" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked6()"> </canvas> <br> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas7" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked7()"> </canvas> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas8" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked8()"> </canvas> 
        <canvas id="myCanvas9" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" onclick="canvasClicked9()"> </canvas> <br>




</body>
```

Comment: This is probably a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Pasting a huge slab of code is not a good idea. Isolate your problem to the minimum code required to reproduce it, then post that. Often that exercise will highlight your error so you don't have to post at all.

Comment: Ok, Rob G. I'll remember that next time. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't make multiple if conditions in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727601/cant-make-multiple-if-conditions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you write

```
if( w1x = true w2x = true && w3x == true) {
```

did you mean

```
if( w1x==true && w2x == true && w3x == true) {
```

or even better

```
if( w1x && w2x && w3x) {
```

Comment: Even better would be to reduce the 8 possible winning combinations to a bit mask (or masks) and test against that (those). ;-)

Comment: @RobG : I'd pitch that to the OP... but perhaps in a month or two!

Comment: Thanks! The error went away, but the alert doesn't show, so I guess that means something in the code is wrong huh?