# checking to see if data attribute has a value or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am quite new to jquery.
i am trying to check on page load if data attribute has a value or is that empty.
here is my html

```
data-tablet="img/xl.jpg"
```

How i wanna check if there is a path set or is it empty.
here is my js

```
if ($('#myImg').data('tablet')=null) {
alert('Path not Set');
};
```

But it's giving me an error.
can you please tell me how to resolve it.
thanks.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality and `===` is identity

Comment: As @blgt says, it's likely to be an issue with your syntax.  It would be useful if you specify in your question what error you're actually seeing however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't make multiple if conditions in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727601/cant-make-multiple-if-conditions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First as pointed out in comments, you are missing an equal sign so you are not doing a comparison. Second issue is that if there is no data attribute it is `undefined`, not `null`.

```
if ($('#myImg').data('tablet')===undefined) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this.

```
if (!$('#myImg').data('tablet')) {
  alert('Path not Set');
};
```

In Javascript every object is convertible to a boolean, so if it's null or an empty string it'll be false, otherwise it'll be true.

Comment: not working.If i omit the data attrabute how can i check if it's there or not?

Comment: If the data attribute doesn't exist then the JQuery data call will return undefined, if the attribute exists but it's blank then JQuery will return an empty string. Both of those evaluate to false, so the exclamation mark at the beginning says to take the opposite of that, which is true, therefore you'll get the alert if the data-tablet attribute is either blank or doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether data attribute have data or exist by using the following code in jquery.

In the beginning, there was typeof. This handy operator gives you the "type" of a javascript value

```
if(typeof $('#myImg').data('tablet') != 'undefined') {
  // data exist
} else {
  // data not exist or undefined
}
```